# Is there a PHP validator?

Tags: php, validation

Is there a PHP validator like there is an HTML validator at w3.org?

Comment: To validate what? PHP’s syntax? You will get a parsing error if the syntax is invalid.

Comment: I think he's on the lookout for something like "lint for PHP". That question has been asked here before: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files in particular, PHPlint (http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/) looks promising.

Answer (score 17):

**You can validate the syntax without running a PHP script itself**, using `php` from the command line, with the option "`-l`" :

```
$ php --help 
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]  
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a
  ...
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  ...
```

For example, with a file that contains :

```
<?php

,


die;

?>
```

*(Note the obvious error)*

You'll get :

```
$ php -l temp.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in temp.php on line 3

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in temp.php on line 3
Errors parsing temp.php
```

**Integrating this in a build process**, or as a pre-commit SVN hook, is nice, btw : it helps avoiding having syntax errors in production ^^

Answer (score 10):

You can run php with the `-l` or `--syntax-check` flag. It checks the syntax of the supplied file without actually running it

```
php --syntax-check myfile.php
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP engine itself.

To turn on error messages:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on what others have said:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Simply using PHP's own error messages is good enough. However, if you really want to get anal and use a set "standard" you can opt for a [PHP Code Sniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer), which for example you can implement as pre-commit hooks to your version control system.

Here's a SO question which explains their usefulness: [How useful is PHP CodeSniffer? Code Standards Enforcement in General?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982333/how-useful-is-php-codesniffer-code-standards-enforcement-in-general)

Answer (score 0):

You might try this one:

https://phpcodechecker.com/

It seems to do a fair job of it. Gets confused about curly braces within strings, but pretty handy.